# rails owner polymorphic route issue (cannot find source associations)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I'm trying to take an existing module, and add a polymorphic ownership associated through it.  Yet, i'm having trouble getting it all set up, and i'm not sure what i'm missing.

I have a priorityPlayer that is owned by a customer (and eventually a team).

```
class PriorityPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail

  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true, touch: true
  validates :owner, presence: true
  validates :player, presence: true
end
```

In my customer model I have

```
has_many :priority_players, as: :owner
```

My schema is set at

```
create_table "priority_players", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.integer  "customer_id"
```

Would anybody know what i am missing here? With what I have right now I'm getting a error at

```
Could not find the source association(s) :pharmacy in model PriorityPharmacy.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an polymorphic association you need two fields on your database to get it working. So following your example priority_players table should have owner_id (integer) and owner_type(string) defined to get it working. owner_id will store the id of the record Ex. 10 and owner_type the class model of the record id Ex. "Customer". Hope it helps.